# How to get That type of respose in retofit library?

Tags: android

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 2,
    "pages": 1,
    "category": {
        "id": 5,
        "slug": "campus",
        "title": "Campus",
        "description": "",
        "parent": 0,
        "post_count": 2
    },
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": 42,
            "type": "post",

            "url": "http://jantasamachar.com/changing-rajya-sabha-presents-modi-with-unique-opportunity-to-unleash-reforms/",
            "status": "publish",
            "title": "Changing Rajya Sabha presents Modi with unique opportunity to unleash reforms",

            "content":
 "date": "2017-08-02 07:00:28",
            "modified": "2017-08-02 07:10:48",
            "categories": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "slug": "campus",
                    "title": "Campus",
                    "description": "",
                    "parent": 0,
                    "post_count": 2
                }
            ],
            "tags": [],
            "author": {
                "id": 1,
                "slug": "admin",
                "name": "admin",
                "first_name": "",
                "last_name": "",
                "nickname": "admin",
                "url": "",
                "description": ""
            },
            "comments": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "comment_count": 0,
            "comment_status": "open",

            "custom_fields": {
                "post_media_position": [
                    "media_full_width"
                ],
                "homepage_slider_add": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "featured_post_add": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "category_slider_add": [
                    "1"
                ],
                "post_sidebar": [
                    "post_sidebar_on"
                ],
                "enable_rating": [
                    "0"
                ]
            },
            "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
            "thumbnail_images": {
                "full": {
                    "url": "http://jantasamachar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nation-1.jpg",
                    "width": 1900,
                    "height": 600
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http://jantasamachar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nation-1-150x150.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "http://jantasamachar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nation-1-300x95.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 95
                },
                "medium_large": {
                    "url": "http://jantasamachar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nation-1-768x243.jpg",
                    "width": 768,
                    "height": 243
                },
                "large": {
                    "url": "http://jantasamachar.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/nation-1-1024x323.jpg",
                    "width": 1024,
                    "height": 323
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: When posting a question, make sure to explain your problem and show an attempt at solving your problem. Your question code formatting is poor aswell please correct it as it makes the question look poor.

Comment: Refer [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216464/how-to-insert-code-properly-on-stack-overflow) to learn How to add a code segment properly in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Best way is by using **GSON**

1. Add GSON dependency in gradle.build
2. Create GSON class for your response shown above. You can use this online tool for that- http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org
3. Set retrofit response type to that class.

That way you can get the above response type using retrofit